# Problem with custom layer in Tensorflow (not calling)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement the Large Margin Cosine Loss in Tensorflow. I've found the following class that does it:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import Constant
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils

def _resolve_training(layer, training):
    if training is None:
        training = K.learning_phase()
    if isinstance(training, int):
        training = bool(training)
    if not layer.trainable:
        # When the layer is not trainable, override the value
        training = False
    return tf_utils.constant_value(training)


class CosFace(keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    Implementation of CosFace layer. Reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09414
    
    Arguments:
      num_classes: number of classes to classify
      s: scale factor
      m: margin
      regularizer: weights regularizer
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 num_classes,
                 s=30.0,
                 m=0.35,
                 regularizer=None,
                 name='cosface',
                 **kwargs):

        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self._n_classes = num_classes
        self._s = float(s)
        self._m = float(m)
        self._regularizer = regularizer

    def build(self, input_shape):
        embedding_shape, label_shape = input_shape
        self._w = self.add_weight(shape=(embedding_shape[-1], self._n_classes),
                                  initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                  trainable=True,
                                  regularizer=self._regularizer)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        """
        During training, requires 2 inputs: embedding (after backbone+pool+dense),
        and ground truth labels. The labels should be sparse (and use
        sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss).
        """
        print('calling CosFace Layer...')
        embedding, label = inputs

        # Squeezing is necessary for Keras. It expands the dimension to (n, 1)
        label = tf.reshape(int(label), [-1], name='label_shape_correction')

        # Normalize features and weights and compute dot product
        x = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embedding, axis=1, name='normalize_prelogits')
        w = tf.nn.l2_normalize(self._w, axis=0, name='normalize_weights')
        cosine_sim = tf.matmul(x, w, name='cosine_similarity')

        training = _resolve_training(self, training)
        if not training:
            # We don't have labels if we're not in training mode
            return self._s * cosine_sim
        else:
            one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(label,
                                        depth=self._n_classes,
                                        name='one_hot_labels')
            theta = tf.math.acos(K.clip(
                    cosine_sim, -1.0 + K.epsilon(), 1.0 - K.epsilon()))
            final_theta = tf.where(tf.cast(one_hot_labels, dtype=tf.bool),
                                   tf.math.cos(theta) - self._m,
                                   tf.math.cos(theta),
                                   name='final_theta')
            print(final_theta)
            output = tf.math.cos(final_theta, name='cosine_sim_with_margin')
            return self._s * output
```

I'm testing it on a simple CNN trained on the MNIST dataset. However the train doesn't work. Here is the Network architecture:

```
label = keras.layers.Input((), name="input/labels")
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=[28,28,1], name="input/image")

margin = CosFace(num_classes=10, dtype='float32')

x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding="same")(input)
x = keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)

x = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same")(x)
x = keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding="same")(x)
x = keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

x = keras.layers.Dense(128)(x)
x = keras.layers.Activation("relu", name="dense")(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = margin([x, label])
output = keras.layers.Activation("softmax")(x)

model_cos = keras.Model(inputs=[input, label], outputs=output)    
model_cos.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
H_cos = model_cos.fit((X_train, y_train), y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=3, verbose=1)
```

And this is the output:

```
Epoch 1/3
calling CosFace Layer...
Tensor("functional_11/cosface/final_theta:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)
calling CosFace Layer...
Tensor("functional_11/cosface/final_theta:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)
860/860 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.3194 - accuracy: 0.9751
Epoch 2/3
860/860 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0545 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/3
860/860 [==============================] - 6s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0368 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

I don't understand what's going on, first of all the real accuracy isn't 1, second of all, it looks like that after the second epoch the CosFace layer is not called anymore.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?